# Please can someone explain how tkinters file dialog works?

Tags: python, tkinter, dll

I've recently taken up a challenge from my friend, However i need to import a .dll to do it. to do this i came up with the following code :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

import ctypes

dll = ctypes.WinDLL(askopenfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*.*")))
```

however this seems to produce errors and I've not actually opened a file dialog yet. Please may someone help me to fix my code or explain why this is going wrong.

EDIT :

the error is :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jakeb/Desktop/New folder/jakes exploit.py", line 6, in <module>
    exploitapi = ctypes.WinDLL(askopenfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*.*")))
  File "C:\Users\jakeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 375, in askopenfilename
    return Open(**options).show()
  File "C:\Users\jakeb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 48, in show
    s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
_tkinter.TclError: bad file type "*.*", should be "typeName {extension ?extensions ...?} ?{macType ?macTypes ...?}?"
>>>
```

p.s. mikes answer is not usefull

Comment: Please provide the error taceback.

Comment: ok will do check the edited question

Comment: why are you using ctypes? You don't need ctypes to use the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
dll = ctypes.WinDLL(askopenfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*.*")))
```

To this:

```
dll = ctypes.WinDLL(askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files","*.*")]))
```

The file type needs to be provided as a list of types. So just add the square brackets.

Comment: Does this really need `ctypes`? `dll = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("All files","*.*")])` should suffice

Comment: i need ctypes to access the dlls features?

Comment: @elitegamer88 what "features"?

Comment: LuaC_getglobal(string service)

to execute lua code

Comment: Well my answer was to solve the original problem of `askopenfilename` you will have to ask a new question for your new error. My answer is the correct answer for your original question.

Comment: but i cant open the file i get a unexpected eol error

Comment: @elitegamer88 the problem was how to use openfiledialog. Your new error is due to the file type or some issue with ctypes. Not file dialog. Please ask a new question related to your new problem.

Comment: Well my question was to allow me to open a file so if I can't open the file than my question is not answerd

Comment: @elitegamer88 ***Please can someone explain how tkinters file dialog works?***... and ... ***not actually opened a file dialog yet. Please may someone help me to fix my code or explain why this is going wrong.*** So your question title and in your question body both ask what is wrong with the filedialog portion. Its really a simple matter. I answered your original question. Just because you ran into another error after that does not mean you should change your question to include the new error. You then need to ask a new question about the new error.

Comment: @elitegamer88 Your little PS at the end of your question is uncalled for. My answer fixed the exact issue of your original question. Just because you do not want to ask a new question for your new issue is your own issue. You will get bad feedback if any if you want to act like that.

Comment: @elitegamer88 I have no idea what that sentence means. If what is right and what is returning?

Comment: @elitegamer88 are you asking why I continue to reply and post my response? If so that is because I very much enjoy this site and would like for others to understand its guidelines and enjoy it as well. I could have simply been bitter and just down voted your question and moved on but I would rather try to improve your understanding of how things work here on Stack Overflow so you can also enjoy the use of this site. Many people out there would simple downvote and move on and then newer users would be discouraged from asking any questions. That is now how I do things.